# How does the Fourier transform of the periodic extension relate to the Fourier series of ? (continuous signal)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

We know that in discrete signals, the relation between the Fourier transform of a signal and its Fourier series coefficient is as follows:

$$X(jkw_0) = 2\pi a_k$$

Or:
$$X(jw) = 2\pi\sum_{k=0}^{k=N}{a_k\delta(w-kw_0)} $$

Which is provable very easily. But what is the relation between CT FS and CT FT? As we know if we have a $x_1(t)$ defined is:

$$x_1(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
        f(t) & |t|< \frac{T_1}{2} \\
        0 & \mbox{oth.}
    \end{array}
\right.$$

We can convolve it into a impulse train to create the periodic function $x_(t)$.

$$x(t) = x_1(t) * \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t-kT)$$

And the fourier transform will be:

$$
X(jw) = X_1(jw) \times F(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t-kT))
$$

$$
X(jw) = X_1(jw) \times \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{jwkT}
$$

Which does not give any indication of any linear relation between CTFS and CTFT of a function.

Comment: The Fourier transform of your impulse train is an impulse train again (Proof: take the Fourier transform of the exponential sum and use that Fourier transform is its own inverse up to signs).

Comment: By the way, I think you/your question should be more clear about this: A function $f: [-T/2, T/2]\to\mathbb{C}$ can be extended to the real line in many ways. Thus you have to be very precise when you talk about The Fourier transform of $f$. In particular, there are multiple sensible questions one may ask. For example "How does the Fourier transform of the periodic extension relate to the Fourier transform of the zero extension?" or "How does the Fourier transform of the periodic extension relate to the Fourier series of $f$?"

Comment: Your question seems to be a mix of these two examples of mine

Comment: @Bananach I know that the FT is an extension of FS. What I wanted to ask was clearly the relation between FS coeffs and the FT of a given signal. In discrete systems there is a clear relation, but I could not find any in continous signals.

Comment: "I know that the FT is an extension of FS" -- that is a meaningless statement. Read my comments, and try to carve out a clear question. Alternatively, just use my first comment about impulse trains to work things out yourself, if you know what you are looking for but find it too difficult to formulate it better.